# IF block executes when the condition does not apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following `IF` block that is supposed to be executed only if my table is empty. But it seems to be executing the code between `BEGIN` and `END` even when my table has a row.

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[KeyProperties]) = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId) VALUES
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=1),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='SocialSecurityNumber'))
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId) VALUES
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='FirstName')),
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='LastName')),
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='Email'))
END
```

The above code throws this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'KeyId', table
>   'MYDATABASE.dbo.KeyProperties'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated. End

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of counting and comparing to 0

2) Use `INSERT INTO tab(col) SELECT`

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[KeyProperties])
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId)
    SELECT
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=1),
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='SocialSecurityNumber');

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId)
   SELECT
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='FirstName')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='LastName'),
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),
      (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='Email');
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable instead:

```
DECLARE @Count INT
(SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[KeyProperties])
IF (@Count = 0)
```

or just

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM [dbo].[KeyProperties])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Not Exists AS Below

```
IF Not Exists(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[KeyProperties])
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId) VALUES
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=1),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='SocialSecurityNumber'))
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyProperties] (KeyId,PropertyId) VALUES
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='FirstName')),
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='LastName')),
    ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE Priority=2),(SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE Name='Email'))
END
```

Comment: Take out the `count` if you are using `exists`